# Can't debug Asp.net Core 1.1 project under "locked down" user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.net Core 1.1 / Swagger project in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 7. I was running under my normal account (i.e. domain\Bob). domain\Bob was in the local admin group on my PC. My company decided to lock down all machines, including dev by removing domain\Bob from the local admin and creating a domain\Bob-Admin account. We're supposed to login as domain\Bob and anything that needs local admin, we have to run as domain\Bob-Admin. Yeah, I know... brilliant.

Anyways, so I created a shortcut to VS2015 on my desktop and set the command like to:

**C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:domain\bob-admin /savecred "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"**

When I try to debug my Asp.Net Core app, I get an error:

**Unable to start process c:\program files\dotnet\dotnet.exe status code 502 bad gateway.**

When I view the error log, I see:

**Process was created with commandline '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" -debug -p "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" -a "C:\Source\xxx\Development\xxx\xxx\xxx\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\xxx.dll" -pidFile "C:\Users\bob-admin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp610B.tmp" -wd "C:\Source\xxx\Development\xxx\xxx\xxx"'but failed to get its status, ErrorCode = '0x80070005'.**

That's an access denied, no? What is it trying to access that it can't. Any way to run this in this scenario?